# Run- Time Error "424" Object Required Filter Pivot Tables

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm looking to filter a pivot table between 2 dates stated in O2 and O3 and can't seem to get rid of this error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub MyFilter()

Dim pvtfld As PivotField
Dim pvtfil As PivotFilter
Dim pvtfils As PivotFilters

Set pvtfld = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date")

For Each pvtfil In pvtfld.PivotFilters

Next pvtfil

Set pvtfil = pvtfils.Add(xlDateBetween, Date, O2, O3, xlDescending)

End Sub
```

Error as below.

> Error 424 Object required appears at set pvtfil line.

Comment: `Set pvtfil = pvtfld.PivotFilters.Add(xlDateBetween, Date, O2, O3, xlDescending)`as`pvtfils`is not set to anything (or`Set pvtfils = pvtfld.PivotFilters`in front of`Set pvtfil`).

Comment: The same error appeared thank you for the help thought :)

Answer (score 0):

The date filter for a pivotfield needs two `String`, which Excel can interprete as date values (neither `Date` values nor `Range` objects can be assigned directly in my German Excel version!).

Therefore I use two date variables "o2" and "o3" which are

- read from a `Range.Value`
- converted to dates by `CDate` (not necessary, if you already used date values in your cells)
- converted to strings by `CStr`

---

```
Sub MyFilter()
    Dim pvtfld As PivotField
    Dim pvtfil As PivotFilter

    Dim o2 As Date
    Dim o3 As Date

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set pvtfld = .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date")
        o2 = CDate(.Range("O2").Value) ' just to ensure, they are dates
        o3 = CDate(.Range("O3").Value)
        Debug.Print CStr(o2), CStr(o3)
        pvtfld.ClearAllFilters
        Set pvtfil = pvtfld.PivotFilters.Add2(Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=CStr(o2), Value2:=CStr(o3), Order:=xlDescending)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but i'm afraid I have a new error message now. Run-time Error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error on the set pvtfil line.

Comment: Did you copy and use exactly and only my code or do you have more code lines in your Sub?

Comment: Yes and I made sure to save before running the code

Comment: The dates in O2 and O3 appear and my pivot tables source data is based on a query could this be causing an issue?

Comment: (I tested it with pivottables with different sources: Range, ListObject and OLAP - all of them work and filter correctly). Please try to record a macro while you manually add a filter "between" some dates. If you can, the recorded macro will help. If you can't add a "between two dates dates" filter manually, then your pivotfield "Date" is based on strings and you can't do it via VBA either.

Comment: How is it? Could you filter manually between two dates and record a macro doing that?